SFMC - SQL usecase
Write a query using SFMC Data View and save the records in data extension having Journey Name, Email, Journey Version, sent, open, bounce.
(NEW DE fields: Journey_Name(text), Email(email), Journery_version, Sent, Opened, Bounced(all numbers)
The solution I wrote in Query Studio is:
SELECT
jou.Journey_Name,
jou.Version_Number
j.Email,
COUNT(s.JobID) AS Sent,
COUNT(o.JobID) AS Opened,
COUNT(b.JobID) AS Bounced,
FROM _Job j LEFT JOIN _Sent s ON j.JobID = s.JobID
LEFT JOIN _Open o ON s.JobID = o.JobID and s.ListID = o.ListID and s.BatchID = o.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = o.SubscriberID and o.IsUnique = 1
LEFT JOIN _Bounce b ON s.JobID = b.JobID and s.ListID = b.ListID and s.BatchID = b.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = b.SubscriberID and b.IsUnique = 1
LEFT JOIN _JourneyActivity ja ON j.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = ja.JourneyActivityObjectID
LEFT JOIN _Journey jou ON ja.VersionID = jou.VersionID
WHERE jou.Journey_Name IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY jou.Journey_Name, jou.Version_Number, j.Email

But its not working, any alternative?

I would rewrite it like this query below. Assume that the email value you want to pull is Subscriber's email address and you are in a child BU.
In case you are in the parent BU, then remove the ENT. part.
SELECT
jou.JourneyName as Journey_Name,
jou.VersionNumber as Version_Number,
sub.EmailAddress as Email,
COUNT(s.JobID) AS Sent,
COUNT(o.JobID) AS Opened,
COUNT(b.JobID) AS Bounced
FROM _Sent s 
INNER JOIN ENT._Subscribers sub ON s.SubscriberID = sub.SubscriberID
LEFT JOIN _Open o ON s.JobID = o.JobID and s.ListID = o.ListID and s.BatchID = o.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = o.SubscriberID and o.IsUnique = 1
LEFT JOIN _Bounce b ON s.JobID = b.JobID and s.ListID = b.ListID and s.BatchID = b.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = b.SubscriberID and b.IsUnique = 1
LEFT JOIN _JourneyActivity ja ON s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = ja.JourneyActivityObjectID
LEFT JOIN _Journey jou ON ja.VersionID = jou.VersionID
WHERE jou.JourneyName IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY jou.JourneyName, jou.VersionNumber, sub.EmailAddress

